# How to add elements dynamically inside a dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase

I am struggling to find a way to creating elements in a dialog box dynamically. How can I create option elements for a select element dynamically? (Where select is created in HTML).
My dialog is created like this in my HTML file:

```
<div id="update_dialog" title="Update Info" style="display: none; ">
   <form >
      <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="dNameId"/></p>
      <p> Province:
          <select id="dprovince">
          </select>
      </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

The following is a function that create these element dynamically. How can I implement this routine for my dialog dynamically?

```
function dialogloadProvinceAndTownList(array1, array2){    
var provinceSlt =document.getElementById('dprovince');
for(var i = 0; i< array1.length; i++){
    var _provinceSlt =document.createElement('option');
    _provinceSlt.value = array1[i];
    _provinceSlt.text = array1[i];
    provinceSlt.appendChild(_provinceSlt);
}   
for(var i = 0; i< array2.length; i++){   
var townSlt =document.getElementById('dtowns');
    var _townSlt =document.createElement('option');
        _townSlt.value = array2[i];
        _townSlt.text = array2[i];
        townSlt.appendChild(_townSlt);
  }
}
```

This is how I call my dialog in JavaScript:

```
function loadUpdate_dialog(){
    
$('#update_dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 345,        
    overlay: {
        opacity: 0.7,
        background: "black"
    },
    buttons: {
        "Update": function() {
            updateEmployeeInfo();
            $(this).dialog('close');                
        },
        "CANCEL": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
        ,
        "Preload Required Data" : function (event, ui) {
            $("#dNameId").val(updateName);
            $("#dSurnameId").val(updateSurname);
            $("#dUsId").val(updateUserId);
            $("#dEmailId").val(updateEmail); 
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is with acknowledgement to input by @Peter suib. I called the method within the dialog routine like this, although Peter's idea of running the routine before I call dialog also works. So I have done it as follow;

```
function loadUpdate_dialog(array1, array){
//Peter I did a test call as you suggested, calling it here too and
//it worked too.

//dialogloadProvinceAndTownList(array1, array); 

$('#update_dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 345,
    
    overlay: {
        opacity: 0.7,
        background: "black"
    },
    
    'TryIt':dialogloadProvinceAndTownList(array1, array),
    
    buttons: {
        "Update": function() {
            updateEmployeeInfo();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        "CANCEL": function() {
            ....
        }
        ,
        "Preload Required Data" : function (event, ui) {
            .... 
        }
    }
  });   
 }
```

But didn't find any documentation that reference to do it like that. If anyone has any reference material on how to work with dialogs which include this kind of functionality. Please refer me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `dialogloadProvinceAndTownList(array1, array2)` in `loadUpdate_dialog()` before displaying your dialog ?

Also, add this in `dialogloadProvinceAndTownList` if you want to call your dialog multiple times with different values in the select elements

```
$(provinceSlt).html('');
$(townSlt).html('');
```

Comment: Ok Peter. I'll try to run it in loadUpdate_dialog(). But now tell me, must I include $(provinceSlt).html(''); and $(townSlt).html(''); inside those loops?

Comment: You need to put `$(provinceSlt).html('');` after the declaration of `var provinceSlt =document.getElementById('dprovince');` and `$(townSlt).html('');` after `var townSlt =document.getElementById('dtowns');`

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot happening with that code so not really sure what/where something isn't working but here is a barebones version of the necessary elements/functionality for adding option to a select element dynamically:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select');
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 let option = document.createElement('option');
 option.textContent = `Option ${i}`;
 select.append(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="select"></select>
```

Comment: The routine works fine don't where and how to fit in the popup dialog.